# How to get the last array from multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that has some other arrays inside it:

if I `print_r($u)` I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
    [41] => Albuquerque
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
    [41] => Albuquerque
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
    [41] => Albuquerque
    [54] => Atlanta
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
    [41] => Albuquerque
    [54] => Atlanta
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
    [41] => Albuquerque
    [54] => Atlanta
    [93] => Auckland
    [94] => Augusta
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany
    [41] => Albuquerque
    [54] => Atlanta
    [93] => Auckland
    [94] => Augusta
)

...
```

The last array has about 20 elements. I need only that last array. Hope this is not too confusing.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have an multi-dimensional array ("array with other arrays inside it"). It looks like you are printing out the array `$u` while you loop though it and add elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`end()`](http://php.net/end) function:

```
$last_array = end($u);
```

Keep in mind that calling `end()` will change the internal array pointer.  If you don't want that to happen, you could do:

```
$last_array = $u[count($u) - 1]; // make sure count($u) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get the last item out of an array `$u`, you can do it with the [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function (regardless of what its type is):

```
$lastarray = end($u);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `$arr = array_slice($u, -1);`? (will return an array containing only your desired array)
Or `$arr = array_pop($u)`? (removes it as well)